# Angular: Access component property in its own selector syntax?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a list of components, something similar to this:

```
<app-component-one   [data]="myData"></app-component-one>
<app-component-two   [data]="myData"></app-component-two>
<app-component-three [data]="myData"></app-component-three>
<app-component-four  [data]="myData"></app-component-four>
```

While the component might look something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-one'
})
export class AppComponentOne implements OnInit {

  @Input() data;

  shouldDisplay;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (data.propertyExists) {
      shouldDisplay = true;
    }
  }
}
```

and I need to hide/show some of these components based on the `shouldDisplay` property **in the component itself**. Is it possible to reference the "self" component in an `ngIf` directive?

Something like this:

```
<app-component-one [data]="myData" *ngIf="self.shouldDisplay"></app-component-one>
```

Is this possible in angular?

Comment: I supuse you can use a reference variable: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars `<app-component-one #componentOne *ngIf="componentOne.shouldDisplay">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding complexity for no reason!

Try using template reference for your component. So in your html you can add a reference like this:

```
<app-component-one #self [data]="myData" *ngIf="self.shouldDisplay"></app-component-one>
```

But you will see that the component will never be visible because the reference is not created yet to be used for `*ngIf` and the reference value is undefined. So you can use this method to access data but you can not use it specifically for `*ngIf`.

You can create a method in parent component to validate if a component should be visible or not! For example in your ts (It's better to use switch case if there are many components):

```
shouldBeVisible(for: string): boolean {
    if (for === 'app-component-one') {
        if (/* conditions based on this.myData */) {
         return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your template:

```
<app-component-one [data]="myData" *ngIf="shouldBeVisible('app-component-one')"></app-component-one>
```